# Tensorflow cannot open MNIST anymore

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am starting to work again on tensorflow. I was relaunching some codes I did a few years ago, it's not working though.

**Old version**

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 20
batch_size = 128  # Decrease batch size if you don't have enough memory
display_step = 1

n_input = 784  # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10  # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

n_hidden_layer = 256 # layer number of features

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'hidden_layer': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_layer])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'hidden_layer': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28, 28, 1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

x_flat = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])

# Hidden layer with RELU activation
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_flat, weights['hidden_layer']),\
    biases['hidden_layer'])
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
# Output layer with linear activation
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(\
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)\
    .minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

From what I have understood the cause comes from the "read_data_sets" and I should use "tf.data". The problem with "tf.data" is that I cannot use that anymore:

```
mnist.train.num_examples
mnist.train.next_batch
```

And the data is not one encoded.

I have tried something like that:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Mandatory: to launch 
#tf.enable_eager_execution() 

mnist_data, info = tfds.load("mnist", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_data["train"], mnist_data["test"]
```

And, mnist_train.batch instead of mnist.train.next_batch

```
# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        total_batch = int(info.splits["train"].num_examples/batch_size)
        print(total_batch)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist_train.batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

With the error:

```
RuntimeError: dataset.__iter__() is only supported when eager execution is enabled.
```

And if I do :

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

I cannot use

```
tf.placeholder()
```

**New version**

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Mandatory: to launch 
#tf.enable_eager_execution() 

mnist_data, info = tfds.load("mnist", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_data["train"], mnist_data["test"]

    import tensorflow as tf

    # Parameters
    learning_rate = 0.001
    training_epochs = 20
    batch_size = 128  # Decrease batch size if you don't have enough memory
    display_step = 1

    n_input = 784  # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
    n_classes = 10  # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

    n_hidden_layer = 256 # layer number of features

    # Store layers weight & bias
    weights = {
        'hidden_layer': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_layer])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer, n_classes]))
    }
    biases = {
        'hidden_layer': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
    }

    # tf Graph input
    x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28, 28, 1])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

    x_flat = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_flat, weights['hidden_layer']),\
        biases['hidden_layer'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

    # Define loss and optimizer
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(\
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)\
        .minimize(cost)

    # Initializing the variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        total_batch = int(info.splits["train"].num_examples/batch_size)
        print(total_batch)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist_train.batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

Comment: what is your old, and what is your new tensorflow version?

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: 1.12.0, last time I used it it was 1.0.0

Comment: How exactly are you intended to use this dataset?

Comment: I want to download MNIST dataset not with mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
because it is not working anymore  and I want to be able to take a batch of the training data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load data using `tfds.load` you get an instance of `tf.data.Dataset`. You cannot feed this directly to a `feed_dict` but rather have to make an iterator and feed the values you obtain from the iterator at each step into the feedable input.You can do something roughly like this:

```
# one hot encode for 10 MNIST classes
def my_one_hot(feature, label):
    return feature, tf.one_hot(label, depth=10)

# load your data from tfds
mnist_train, train_info = tfds.load(name="mnist", with_info=True, as_supervised=True, split=tfds.Split.TRAIN)

# convert your labels in one-hot
mnist_train = mnist_train.map(my_one_hot)

# you can batch your data here
mnist_train = mnist_train.batch(8)
```

Then you can launch your graph (and initialize your iterator)

```
# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # make an iterator
    train_iterator = mnist_train.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_element = train_iterator.get_next()

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):

        sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
        batch_train_x, batch_train_y = sess.run(next_element)

        total_batch = int(train_info.splits["train"].num_examples/batch_size)
        print(total_batch)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_train_x, y: batch_train_y})
```

For more infor on `tf.data.Dataset` look at the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I have just one last question I have read on this blog https://dominikschmidt.xyz/tensorflow-data-pipeline/ that I actually shoudn't use feed_dict. I have tried to transpose his use-case to mine but it is not working. Any idea ?

Comment: Problem solved by following this tutorial https://cs230-stanford.github.io/tensorflow-input-data.html#building-an-image-data-pipeline from stanford.